# How to find an element in an array based on the value of an array porp

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retrieve an object in an array of objects based on that object property value. This is my array:

```
const address_components = [
  {
    long_name: "11237",
    short_name: "11237",
    types: ["postal_code"]
  },
  {
    long_name: "Kings County",
    short_name: "Kings County",
    types: ["political, administrative_area_level_2"]
  },
  {
    long_name: "New York",
    short_name: "NY",
    types: ["political", "administrative_area_level_1"]
  },
  {
    long_name: "United States",
    short_name: "US",
    types: ["political", "country"]
  }
];
```

I want to retrieve the object that contains "country" in the `types` property. I tried doing

```
var result = address_components.filter( obj => {
      return obj.types === "country";
    });
console.log(result);
// logs undefined
```

And the console logs `undefined`. However, when I try this filter method with another property I get the object.

```
var result = address_components.filter( obj => {
  return obj.short_name === "US";
});
console.log(result);
// logs object
```

Does anyone know how to can I filter the array based on the items in the `types` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type` is an array, you can use `includes` to check if the array contains the string.

```js
const address_components = [{
    long_name: "11237",
    short_name: "11237",
    types: ["postal_code"]
  },
  {
    long_name: "Kings County",
    short_name: "Kings County",
    types: ["political", "administrative_area_level_2"]
  },
  {
    long_name: "New York",
    short_name: "NY",
    types: ["political", "administrative_area_level_1"]
  },
  {
    long_name: "United States",
    short_name: "US",
    types: ["political", "country"]
  }
];

var result = address_components.filter(obj => {
  return obj.types.includes("country");
});
console.log(result);
```

---

Using multiple search parameters, you can use `some()`

```js
const address_components = [{long_name: "11237",short_name: "11237",types: ["postal_code"]}, {long_name: "Kings County",short_name: "Kings County",types: ["political", "administrative_area_level_2"]},{long_name: "New York",short_name: "NY",types: ["political", "administrative_area_level_1"]},{long_name: "United States",short_name: "US",types: ["political", "country"]}];

var result = address_components.filter(obj => {
  return obj.types.some(o => ['country', 'postal_code'].includes(o));
});
console.log(result);
```

Doc: [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Since @vanegeek wants a single element it is probably easier to use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which will give you the first element where the predicate is true.

Comment: @schroffl That is a good point. If OP only needs the first match, they can use `find()`

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your answers! @Eddie is it possible to retrieve the objects based on different matches. Say i want to types "country" OR "postal_code"?

Comment: @vanegeek It is possible. Can you give an example of example `country` and `postal_code` You are trying to filter?

Comment: @Eddie yes so say in the array I posted in the question i want to retrieve the objects that have "country" or "postal_code" as the value in their types prop.  Kind of something like this ```var result = address_components.filter(obj => {
  return obj.types.includes("country" || "postal_code");
});```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed @Eddie! Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `.short_name` is a string, whereas `types` is an array. Checking equivalence (`==`) works with a string, but you need to check for membership with an array.

Also, if your arrow functions are that simple, you can omit the curly brackets:

```
let result = address_components.filter(obj => obj.types.includes('country'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `types` it's an array, you should use `indexOf` method.

> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the
>   search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

The advantages of `indexOf` over `includes` is that `indexOf` is supported by old browsers and `includes` not.

```js
const address_components = [{
    long_name: "11237",
    short_name: "11237",
    types: ["postal_code"]
  },
  {
    long_name: "Kings County",
    short_name: "Kings County",
    types: ["political, administrative_area_level_2"]
  },
  {
    long_name: "New York",
    short_name: "NY",
    types: ["political", "administrative_area_level_1"]
  },
  {
    long_name: "United States",
    short_name: "US",
    types: ["political", "country"]
  }
];

var result = address_components.filter(obj => {
  return obj.types.indexOf("country") > -1;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here different performances using different methods http://jsben.ch/jmHQg

The fastest is using `.filter()` and `.includes()` it's interesting that `.map()` and `.includes()` have the worst performance, at least in this implementation:

```
var result = [];
  address_components.map(obj => {

      if(obj.types.includes("country")){
          result.push(obj);
      }
  });
  console.log(result);
```