# When does for loop, .map() or .filter() have better performance?

Tags: javascript

Based in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373687/how-to-find-an-element-in-an-array-based-on-the-value-of-an-array-porp/50373935#50373935) question, the idea is look for objects in an array of objects based on some property value that those object could have, so I made this script to check which method is faster:

```
const elementsInObject = 1000000;
const lengthOfItems = 5;

//just random text
function randomText() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (var i = 0; i < lengthOfItems; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}


//ccreation of object
console.time("creatingObject");
var arrObj = [];
for (let i = 0; i < elementsInObject; i++) {
  let el = {
    prop1: randomText(),
    prop2: randomText(),
    types: [randomText(), randomText()]
  };

  arrObj.push(el);
}
console.timeEnd("creatingObject");


console.time("forFor");
var result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arrObj.length; i++) {

     for(let q=0; q<arrObj[i].types.length; q++){

        if (arrObj[i].types[q] == "abcde") {
            result.push(arrObj[i]);
          }

     }

    }
console.timeEnd("forFor");

console.time("forIncludes");
var result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arrObj.length; i++) {
  if (arrObj[i].types.includes("abcde")) {
    result.push(arrObj[i]);
  }
}
console.timeEnd("forIncludes");

console.time("filterIncludes");
var result = arrObj.filter(obj => {
  return obj.types.includes("abcde");
});
console.timeEnd("filterIncludes");

console.time("mapIncludes");
var result = [];
arrObj.map(obj => {
  if (obj.types.includes("abcde")) {
    result.push(obj);
  }
});
console.timeEnd("mapIncludes");

console.time("filterIndexOf");
var result = arrObj.filter(obj => {
  return obj.types.indexOf("abcde") > -1;
});
console.timeEnd("filterIndexOf");
```

The idea is to check which method is faster and scalable, I find in this example that for inside for is the fastest algorithm to resolve this (in node and chrome, not firefox).  So the question is: When filter() or map() have better performance than for?

Comment: https://jsperf.com/ run tests

Comment: arrObj[x].types, where did types come from?

Comment: `So the question is: When filter() or map() have better performance than for?` the answer is - if you ever get to a situation where there is a performance bottleneck, you can run a performance test.

Comment: @vlaz I know, but I'd like a generic solution

Comment: @HMR I had changed the property.

Comment: For what? In the vast majority of cases performance wouldn't matter. If you're going over an array with 10 elements and you only do it once, it's such a miniscule part of your application that microoptimising prematurely it would yield nothing. In some cases the JS engine will optimise the code for you, so there cannot even be a "generic" solution that will 100% of the time work the same way. Moreover, JS engines will differ between environments and can even differ between versions. If Chrome optimise their `.map` tomorrow, your "generic" solution changes. Stop prematurely optimising.

Comment: After looking at your test cases, it would help if you even knew what you're trying to do. That `.map` test is actually quite bad as *you are misusing `.map`*. I simply changed it to `.forEach` and I've reduced the execution time by about 75% (over very few tests, so I may be off) ~200ms -> 50ms. You aren't doing anything with `.map` that you cannot do with `.forEach`, in fact, you're making a whole new array for no apparent reason, which is why the execution time is inflated.

Comment: @vlaz it's obvious that if I have 10 elements it doesn't matter. But if I have 10 millions it's not the same.

Comment: @Emeeus again, that's not "generic". A "generic" solution will also apply to 10 elements.

Comment: @vlaz change "generic" for "scalable" if you wish.

Comment: It still depends on factors like where you're using this and what you're using it for. Again, Chrome could end up optimising one approach or another tomorrow. Or not. And yet again, it would help if you use methods properly, as it's less "wasteful" and the JS engine might further optimise things for you.

Comment: @vlaz then we shouldn't take care of performance in your opinion

Comment: @Emeeus no, you are putting words in my moth - I initially said you should profile *your application* and do that *when you need it*.  It's because we shouldn't care about *premature* optimisation, not optimisation in general. Assuming you get a solution today, it could be invalid tomorrow. Assuming you get a solution today for *this* dataset it could be invalid for a different one. Assuming you get a solution today, it might not be relevant for your application because a bigger bottleneck is elsewhere. And so on. If there was an optimal approach, we wouldn't have others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably filer would be the best, your loops perform well because you end up with empty arrays but if that's not the case your loops are performing push operations.

Includes would likely perform slightly better than indexOf but not noticeably.

In comments you note that you'd like a general method to filter, using a getter and a comparer is pretty general [full example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075368/1641941).

```js
const elementsInObject = 5000000;

//random number between 1 and 11
function randomNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1
}

console.time("createObjectArray");
var arrObj = [...new Array(elementsInObject)].map(()=>({
  prop3: [randomNum(),randomNum()]
}));
console.timeEnd("createObjectArray");

const filterFn = getter => comparer => o =>
  comparer(getter(o));

//get a property
const getProp3 = o => o.prop3;
//you can write getB I'm sure

// compare contains
const contains = needle => haystack =>
  haystack.includes(needle);

// compare indexOf
const indexOf = needle => haystack =>
  haystack.indexOf(needle)>-1;

const filterProp3 = filterFn(getProp3);

console.time("filterContains");
arrObj.filter(
  filterProp3(contains(1))
);
console.timeEnd("filterContains");

console.time("filterIndexOf");
arrObj.filter(
  filterProp3(indexOf(1))
);
console.timeEnd("filterIndexOf");
console.log(
  "Items found:",
  arrObj.filter(
    filterProp3(contains(1))
  ).length
);
```

Comment: Just to reinforce what I said in comments, different engines can handle things differently. In Firefox, I'm getting ~12ms for `contains` and ~10ms for `indexOf`. Hardly a worthwhile difference but the latter is faster. In Chrome, `contains` finishes in ~37-40ms and `indexOf` in ~50ms.

Comment: @vlaz I sometimes get includes a little slower than indexOf but the difference is negligible, most of the time it's includes that's faster. if this has to run in a browser and you have many items you must run it in a web worker.